# Problems with Commonwealth Bank MIGS payment gateway not returning some customers to returnURL

Tags: payment-gateway

I'm only posting this here in the hope that someone else may be suffering the same problem, search StackOverflow and spot this and see if anyone else is seeing the same issues so I can tell the helpdesk we're not an isolated case.

Every night/day we get approx 50-60 transactions on our website where the payment gateway is the Commonwealth Bank's MIGS egateway. Every single one of those transactions originates from the same page and, apart from amount and customer ID, the same parameters are sent to the commonwealth bank.

Approximately half of those customers get stranded on a blank page after being redirected back to the same URL on our webserver. There's no common cause and some successful transactions come through only minutes after a failed one and vice-versa.

The helpdesk claims that every single transaction where it fails to return to us is exactly the same from their end as the ones that successfully return to us, so we're at an absolute loss.  All testing with their test gateway works perfectly - we've never been stranded on a blank page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in the hope this helps someone else one day - here was the answer (for us, anyway).  The "redirect URL" we were passing MIGS (the page on our site the end user should come back to AFTER the transaction) was plain "http".  We changed it to be https (note that FireFox and Chrome has been updating their browser security with respect to http/https mixed on pages) and this has completely cured out problem. All transactions now work correctly.